# Remove x amount of elements with .remove()

Tags: jquery

I am not seeing any clear documentation on removing a certain amount of elements without it being in a specific order, of course there are many ways to remove a list of say 5 items, if they are in that order. What if there is elements that you don't want removed in between? Let me show you an example

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7NRLN/3/)**: Below is just pieces from this fiddle, it would be easier just taking a look at the fiddle.

HTML

```
<div class="item empty">Empty</div>
<div class="item empty">Empty</div>
<div class="item editable">Editable</div>
<div class="item empty">Empty</div>

</div>

<button class="demo">Demo</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('.demo').click(function() {
var length = $('.item').length,
    columns = 12/6,
    addColumn = columns - length

//Set this for subtracting elements if addColumn is a negitive number    
if(addColumn < 0) {
    //Want to remove the amount of items which is -2 in this case
    //Obviously I just threw in .eq just for the petes sake, but not sure about the syntax
    $('.item.empty').eq(/*Remove whatever amount of addColumn */ ).remove()
}

//Equals -2
alert(addColumn)

});
```

So just to be clear, I am trying to remove the amount of `.empty` items based on whatever the amount is passed into the `addColumn` variable in this case its static set at -2.

So I ask if `addColumn < 0` is a negative number then we do subtraction using `.remove()` and I need to remove the amount of `.empty` items equal to the `addColumn` variable.

12/6 comes from a 12 column grid and the 6 is a two column layout `span6` `span6` and so if the layout is set at 4 columns we need to remove 2 columns, which is where the -2 comes from.

Comment: do you want to remove the last 2 empty items

Comment: like in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gj7QA/1/

Comment: No Eariler I was just removing the `.last()` column but I need a more dynamic solution, because the items change, its not a static order.. So I want to remove 2 `.empty` no specific order really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) will do the job

```
$('.item.empty').slice(addColumn).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gj7QA/)

Comment: Both answers are good, I came across both them nice it makes sense now.

Comment: Looks like `.slice()` is what I need

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for the [`:lt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/):

```
    $('.item.empty:lt('+num+')').remove(); // zero-based index
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/D5k6D/

You can also pass a negative index  to [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to remove the *last* `num-1` elements:

```
    $('.item.empty:gt('+(-1-num)+')').remove(); // 'num' is positive
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/bG2qq/

Comment: Yeah I actually thought about something like this I read about `:lt` but for some reason I kept thinking adding a transverse before remove.

Comment: Oh and actually I was going to use this exact syntax, but what held me back was I thought `:lt` only removes items bunched in an order, not out of random order.

Comment: See this does what I thought though if an item is not in order it wont remove the amount.. http://jsfiddle.net/7NRLN/5/

Comment: I don't understand why you're passing a negative index to `:lt`. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/D5k6D/

Comment: Yeah I see why a negative wouldnt work.. sorry bout that but I need to `.slice()` out the `.empty` items

Comment: No, im changing columns and if say the user is on 4 columns then changes the layout to become a 2 column layout I need to remove 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use lo dash or underscore to get the first items from the array and remove them, i.e.

```
$(_.first($('.item.empty'), -addColumn)).remove();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/7NRLN/6/.